# Meaning of "indispensable" in Thoreau quote

Tags: quotes, comprehension

> Most of the luxuries, and many of the so called comforts of life, are not only indispensable, but positive hinderances to the elevation of mankind. ~ "Walden", Henry David Thoreau

In my dictionary indispensable means "absolutely necessary", but if we substitute that in the above quote seems nonsensical, but I can't find any mention online of this apparent... typo? Maybe he meant to write "not indispensable", or "dispensable"? Am I reading or understanding this quote incorrectly?

Offending sources:

- http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/h/henrydavid132501.html
- https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/340961-most-of-the-luxuries-and-many-of-the-so-called
- Forbes "quote of the day" today

Comment: Note the spelling of 'hindrances'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a transcription error.

Comment: Works for me, @chaslyfromUK, so I voted "blatantly off-topic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are quoting it wrong. It is indeed "not indispensable":

> Most of the luxuries and many of the so-called comforts of life are **not only not indispensable**, but positive hindrances to the elevation of mankind.

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=B7qEq-OvyKMC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=thoreau%20indispensable%20comforts%20of%20life&source=bl&ots=SUE9lGUHFp&sig=n6N3tB3yWFvtd60QD0hqYvjfPRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwB2oVChMIlLCI153xyAIVyZhyCh1M_ga-#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Thoreau was a strong believer in simplicity of living, so you are correct when you say that "not only indispensable" makes no sense.

You can also verify the quote [on Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Walden) (Chapter 1, Economy).

Comment: I didn't think to check the original -- oops. I found this misquoted on Forbes, Brainy Quote, and Good Reads. Thank you for a good answer.

Comment: No problem, David. Glad I could help.

Comment: He was a strong believer in simplicity of living so long as he could walk into Concord and [sponge off his friends](http://thoreau.eserver.org/smith.html). I live near Walden Pond, so I can tell you it's not a very long way into the wilderness, even by the standards of the day.

Comment: Nothing in the article you linked, @Robusto, suggested that he ate more than occasionally with friends; in fact, the article supports the view that he ate a lot of rice and beans. It also states that "It should be obvious to anyone who’s read Walden that Thoreau was not a hermit", and having read Walden, I agree. None of this adds up to Thoreau being a hypocrite.

Comment: Never said he was a hermit or a hypocrite. And the article does support that he was seen frequently in Concord. I just don't think he was the glorious independent he's often imagined to have been.